Identify species
Would like to know if anyone knows what this is!?
Was attached to human hair off scalp 1/8 inch long


Looks like dust fibre

Welcome Jennifer. There doesn't seem to be anything in the picture or the text to lead us to believe there even is an organism there. Can you clarify?

There was movement and it looked 2 me as two eyes

The first photo object is a few mm (2-4 mm?) length based on those being fingerprints in the background. How big is the second object. If it is smaller, then the tiniest breeze, even the heat rising from your body could make it move, as could slight tremors in your hand.
